# Equality checking after copying fragments of int

Tags: c, pointers

It is known that an uninitialized local variable has indeterminate value and using it invokes undefined behavior. But do operations like copying fragments using pointers and checking for equality afterwards also lead to undefined behavior?

The following compiles and runs smoothly, but I am unsure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int p;
    int q = 1;

    char *_p = (char *)&p;
    char *_q = (char *)&q;

    size_t n;
    for(n = 0; n < sizeof(int); n++) {
        memcpy(_q++, _p++, sizeof(char));
    }

    if (p == q) {
        printf("Equal!!!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using any unitialized variable or memory is Undefined Behaviour. Since you are copying from unintialized memory then yes any operations using the result of that copy is Undefined Behavior too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying uninitialised memory over initialised memory. The end result is that the contents of both memory locations will be identical, and hence match.  As the source was uninitialised, it's value cannot be guaranteed; once you copy this value over the previously initialised value, you are wiping out whatever that was set to and replacing it with the unknown value.

Hence they will match.

Although your copy routine is a little excessive, I imagine you are aware of that and purely using it for experimentation :)

Comment: "copying initalised memory over uninitalised memory". It's the other way around. OP is copying *from* uninitialized memory. That is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: OOPS! Yes the copy is the other way around.  However the result of the comparison will not be undefined, as the result will be that both integer values (although undefined) will be exact copies of each other and match.

Comment: No that's wrong. The compiler can do whatever it likes once UB is encountered. It's likely that the values are the same but it is still UB because there is no requirement or guarantee that the implementation will give that result every time.

Comment: Why would copying one memory location to another memory location not yield both locations as being equal?  The compiler is not involved at the point of execution, and the code in this situation is dealing with pointers to memory.

Comment: @Graeme Google "trap representation"

Comment: @Graeme You are making assumptions on what instructions the compiler will generate. You cannot do that when UB is involved. For example, since the variable is unintialized the compiler could very well replace it with a `0` at the point of comparison. I'm not saying any compiler does that but a compiler can do that and still conform perfectly to the C standard.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for that, very interesting.  I imagine the more complex a type the more likely it is to have a trap representation.  (hence unsigned char not having one)

Comment: @Graeme Unsigned char is specifically exempted from having trap representations so that you can use it to copy arbitrary data, which could require accessing padding bytes between structure elements.

Comment: @kaylum but does it not also have to allocate memory for the undefined location, especially as it then has to provide a pointer to it's location.  EG using an array of char to allocate a block of RAM.  Obviously clear that RAM with memset before using it.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up @Jonathan, you are not dealing with undefined behavior but an undefined value. The undefined value is copied just fine.

What would be undefined if you attempted to do something like divide by an undefined value, which might be zero. Or worse, assigning a value through an undefined pointer.

```
    int *p;
    int q = 1;

    char *p = q;
```

Try the later and you may very well segment fault, and if you don't, you are likely walking over some random memory position; often not noticed in small, short-lived, programs, but a  horrible problem for large, long-lived, programs.

Turning on aggressive compiler checks will likely catch the simple cases. The more obscure cases present severe debugging challenges.